# CSRF web application Vulnerability

Tags: java, security, tomcat6

How to prevent CSRF in Servlets?I searched on net about this and found following filter configuration will prevent,but i want to understand how these filter configuration works.

```
<filter>
<filter-name>CSRFPreventionFilter</filter-name>
<filter-class>
org.apache.catalina.filters.CsrfPreventionFilter
</filter-class>
<init-param>
<param-name>entryPoints</param-name>
<param-value>/PATH</param-value>
</init-param>
</filter
<filter-mapping>
<filter-name>CSRFPreventionFilter</filter-name>
<url-pattern>/PATH/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping> 

I am using Tomcat 6 server and java 6.
```

Answer (score 0):

Please read [the source code](https://github.com/apache/tomcat/blob/c3d2d375ce372fa95efec4043a091fc8a5693f02/java/org/apache/catalina/filters/CsrfPreventionFilter.java). It is very short and easy.

Excerpt:

```
String previousNonce =
    req.getParameter(Constants.CSRF_NONCE_REQUEST_PARAM);

if (nonceCache == null || previousNonce == null ||
        !nonceCache.contains(previousNonce)) {
    res.sendError(getDenyStatus());
    return;
}
```

How to use the filter:
https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/filter.html#CSRF_Prevention_Filter

For more details of CSRF:
https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet